# Ruby on Rails - uninitialized constant Mail::TestMailer (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Been having an issue with my production ruby on rails app and I cannot figure out what is wrong.

I am not using any mailers and I have tried making a Mail::TestMailer constant, I have tried finding references to Mail::TestMailer and found none. application_mailer.rb has not been changed at all, just the default file.

```
uninitialized constant Mail::TestMailer (NameError)
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionmailer-6.1.7/lib/action_mailer/delivery_methods.rb:42:in `<module:ClassMethods>'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionmailer-6.1.7/lib/action_mailer/delivery_methods.rb:40:in `<module:DeliveryMethods>'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionmailer-6.1.7/lib/action_mailer/delivery_methods.rb:8:in `<module:ActionMailer>'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionmailer-6.1.7/lib/action_mailer/delivery_methods.rb:5:in `<main>'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionmailer-6.1.7/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:438:in `<class:Base>'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionmailer-6.1.7/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:437:in `<module:ActionMailer>'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionmailer-6.1.7/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:12:in `<main>'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
  /var/www/APPNAME/releases/10/app/mailers/application_mailer.rb:1:in `<main>'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:30:in `require'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in `const_get'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in `cget'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:169:in `block in actual_eager_load_dir'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:40:in `block in ls'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `each'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `ls'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:164:in `actual_eager_load_dir'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `each'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `block in eager_load'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `synchronize'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `eager_load'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:296:in `block in eager_load_all'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:294:in `each'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:294:in `eager_load_all'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:133:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
  /var/www/APPNAME/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails
```

Comment: You say you are not using mailers. Please add the contents of `app/mailers/application_mailer.rb` to your question. That is what the stack trace is pointed at.

Comment: Here is the code in the application mailer
`code
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'from@example.com'
  layout 'mailer'
end
`

Comment: I have similar issue on ubuntu 20.04. I have other rails apps running fine on the same server. I deployed a new server and it exploded with this error.

Comment: @JohnCoday Did you find a solution for this? I have the exact same error!